# What is minimum number of edges in graph such that there exist $2$ edges in each $4$ vertices?

Tags: graph-theory

I think the minimum for $8$-vertex graph is $5$ edges, for $10$-vertex graph — $7$ edges (I suppose degree of each vertex in $n$-vertex graph is $n-3$).
(I encountered this problem in one of the collections of math problems on the Internet, I don't remember it exactly.)

Comment: Maybe I'm just being obtuse, but I don't understand what you mean by "such that there exist 2 edges in each 4 vertex". Could you clarify?

Comment: Each 4 vertexes include 2 couples (2 edges). Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: OK, I think I see: by "in each 4 vertex" you mean "in each subgraph of order 4"?

Comment: Wait, but that doesn't work . . . you can easily construct a graph with 4 vertices and 5 edges, which means that you can easily construct a graph with 8 vertices and 5 edges that has a subgraph with 4 vertices and 0 edges.

Comment: Oh, wait, I do see: you're not looking for the minimum value such that *every* graph has this property, you're looking for the minimum value below which *no* graph has this property. Is that right?

Comment: Thank you for explanation, I edited it.

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Answer (score 0):

Some thing doesn't add up, I think the original question you meant asks for something else.

I assume that every induced subgraph of order $4$ has exactly two edges.

Clearly degree of each vertex is at most $2$; else the induced subgraph on this vertex along with its three neighbours has at least $3$ edges. This degree restriction limits the components in our graphs to be either paths, or cycles, or isolated vertices.

We can reject any component being a cycle, else we can always find consecutive $4$ vertices that induce three edges among them (and $C_3$ is also rejected). For similar reasons the components which are paths must be of order at most $3$.

It is easy to see that the only possible graphs are:

1. $P_2 \cup P_2$
2. $P_3 \cup K_1$

So the answer to your question of #minimum edges in such graphs is such graphs is $2$.

But I am sure you were looking for something else.